# AWS RDS Postgres, GORM and transient errors

Tags: postgresql, go, amazon-rds, go-gorm

I'm using Golang, GORM and a Cloud DB (AWS RDS Postgres)

With that in mind, we all know transient errors are natural and expected in cloud environments, therefore database operations should be resilient to this kind of errors.
That said, does GORM/sql driver provide this mechanism out of the box or any builtin support for determining which errors are safe to retry?
Or do I need to handle resilience strategies and retry logics manually?
If so, are there any popular libraries/tools of choice specific to golang?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GORM, you can use the built-in error handling, such as

```
if err := db.Where("name = ?", "jinzhu").First(&user).Error; err != nil {
  // error handling...
}
```

Here's a [list of o all the possible GORM errors to handle](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/master/errors.go)

And here's an example to retry connections to a SQL server with GORM.

```
type errorLogger func(err error, msg string)

// NewPostgresDb creates a db instance, if connection fails, panics. With re-try functionality.
// logger may be nil.
func NewPostgresDb(connectionUrl string, retries int, logger errorLogger) *gorm.DB {
    var db *gorm.DB
    var err error
    db, err = gorm.Open("postgres", connectionUrl)
    for err != nil {
        if logger != nil {
            logger(err, fmt.Sprintf("Failed to connect to database (%d)", retries))
        }
        if retries > 1 {
            retries--
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
            db, err = gorm.Open("postgres", connectionUrl)
            continue
        }
        panic(err)
    }
    db.SingularTable(true)
    return db
}
```

Comment: So I need to handle erros manually, I mean, there is no built in way to handle well known transient faults, checking postgres error codes ??

Comment: You could look into something like this: https://github.com/craigmj/golly